# WebScraping Video on a Youtube Channel Using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-analysis

How do I get the video title and links of the videos on a youtube channel?

What I want is to build a web scraper with BeautifulSoup that extracts all the titles, views, dislikes and likes, comments and dates published from videos on a youtube channel.

The approach I'm using is to first extract the titles of the video ad URL then use the URL to get the details about the video.

So far I've not had any luck. below is a test url

```
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/c/AlexTheAnalyst/videos'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this I have extract youtube videos these code help you:

```
from selenium import webdriver
    PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
    url='https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8tgRQ7DOzAbn9L7zDL8mLg'
    driver =webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
    driver.get(url)
    videos = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("style-scope ytd-grid-video-renderer")
    
    for video in videos:
        title=video.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="video-title"]').text
        days= video.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="metadata-line"]/span[2]').text
        views= video.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="metadata-line"]/span[1]').text
    
        print(title,days,views)
```

Comment: but  you have to install `selenium driver` and `chrome driver`

Comment: Please how do I create a chrome driver path on my mac

Comment: first you have downlaod the chrome driver in C drive and then where you paste the driver in C you have given the location of driver to the selenium

Comment: just that I have given  location of  driver  where I have paste in computer in my code given to `path`